# How to georeference city data set with geoid and objectid as only location data

Tags: carto, georeferencing, geoid

I am new to Cartodb and ran into my first hiccup. I was trying to import a data set of walkable food access in Philadelphia that is available from Open Data Philly. I can't figure out how to georeference the map as there is only 3 columns...

OBJECTID 3848   GEOID 421010125003026  ACCESS_  High Access

What is GEOID? Does this have to be connected to some kind of library to mean anything?

Comment: yes this would have to be associated with some kind of coordinate data to be shown on a map. can you add a link to the data source?

Answer (score 3):

If this is the walkable food data:
https://www.opendataphilly.org/dataset/philadelphia-food-access/resource/07f115d1-5b8e-4620-9720-9c310ba29896

Download the zipped shapefile (or kml), go to your data dashboard on Cartodb (http://yourname.cartodb.com/dashboard/datasets), and drag the zipfile onto the page:

[image]

It's already "georeferenced" - but maybe this isn't the data you expected? All it shows are areas (polygons) of Philadephia divided in several classes of "access": high, low, moderate, etc.

To see these in CartoDB, go to the map view, "Wizards" (paintbrush button on the right), and select "Categories", using "Access" as the category to map:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't know how to do! New to this so didn't know that the KML file is how to get polygon data into Cartodb. I kept trying to use the CSV file. Thanks! I'll give it a try now.

Comment: that would explain it... csv could work if it had latitude and longitude specified (for points), or city or country names (cartodb can georeference many of these), but not with just non-geographic attributes